# python script to carve up csv data

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have some csv data that looks like this:

```
724 "Overall evaluation: 2
Invite to interview: 2
Strength or novelty of the idea (1): 3
Strength or novelty of the idea (2): 3
Strength or novelty of the idea (3): 2
Use or provision of open data (1): 3
Use or provision of open data (2): 3
""Open by default"" (1): 2
""Open by default"" (2): 2
Value proposition and potential scale (1): 3
Value proposition and potential scale (2): 4
Market opportunity and timing (1): 3
Market opportunity and timing (2): 4
Triple bottom line impact (1): 4
Triple bottom line impact (2): 3
Triple bottom line impact (3): 2
Knowledge and skills of the team (1): 4
Knowledge and skills of the team (2): 4
Capacity to realise the idea (1): 4
Capacity to realise the idea (2): 4
Capacity to realise the idea (3): 3
Appropriateness of the budget to realise the idea: 4"
724 "Overall evaluation: 1
Invite to interview: 1
Strength or novelty of the idea (1): 2
Strength or novelty of the idea (2): 2
Strength or novelty of the idea (3): 3
Use or provision of open data (1): 2
Use or provision of open data (2): 2
""Open by default"" (1): 3
""Open by default"" (2): 3
Value proposition and potential scale (1): 2
Value proposition and potential scale (2): 2
Market opportunity and timing (1): 2
Market opportunity and timing (2): 2
Triple bottom line impact (1): 2
Triple bottom line impact (2): 2
Triple bottom line impact (3): 1
Knowledge and skills of the team (1): 4
Knowledge and skills of the team (2): 2
Capacity to realise the idea (1): 2
Capacity to realise the idea (2): 2
Capacity to realise the idea (3): 1
Appropriateness of the budget to realise the idea: 3"
```

using python and regex, would it be possible to identify every instance of the words `"Overall evaluation:` and log that number, in this example `724` and the value that comes after`"Overall evaluation:`, i.e. `2`, such that we would be left with:

```
724, 2
724, 1
```

for instance.

If so, how to implement such logic?

I tried like this:

```
f=open("1.txt",'r').read().splitlines()
head='0'
body=[]
for x in f:
    if x=="\n" or x.strip()=='':
        continue
    try:
        int(x[0])
        print(head +':'+'+'.join(body))
        tmp=x.split()
        head=tmp[0]+'-'+tmp[1]
        body=[tmp[4]]
    except ValueError as e:
        body.append(x.split(':')[1].strip().strip('\"'))
print(head +':'+'+'.join(body))
```

but it didn't work :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should do the work:

```
lines=open("1.txt",'r').read().splitlines()
for l in lines:
    data = l.split(' "Overall evaluation: ')
    if len(data) == 2:
        print(data[0] + ", " + data[1])
```

The split function use the string `"Overall evaluation:` as a seperator

Comment: I would split with ' "Overall evaluation: ', including the whitespaces... but a fine answer.

Comment: @user2177047 fixed